# kable table not properly rendering on website

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, blogdown

I use the R package, `blogdown`, to manage my website. The table I created is rendering as a standard(?) markdown table after saving and `serve_site` even though I'm using `knitr::kable`. But when I knit the chunk in a different RMarkdown file, it renders properly. Here's the code chunk.

````
```{r eda-tab, echo=FALSE}

knitr::kable(matrix(c(
      '7 yrs', '67%',
      '6 yrs', '78%',
      '5 yrs', '86%',
      '4 yrs', '92%',
      NULL
), ncol = 2, byrow=TRUE, dimnames = list(NULL, c('Cutoff', '% Remaining'))),
booktabs=TRUE, caption = 'Inductees')
```
````

[image: website rendering]

[image: knitted rendering]

I'm using the [hugo-octopress theme](https://github.com/parsiya/Hugo-Octopress). It may be an issue with the theme but I don't think the creator is an R user so I'm not sure how to address it with them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`knitr::kable()` outputs an HTML table when used to generate blogdown posts. The reason that it looks "standard" is because [the CSS styling](https://github.com/parsiya/Hugo-Octopress/blob/a8d0587810a6459fc07d01e947ad50cabfab142d/static/css/hugo-octopress.css#L2143-L2153) that is applied to the table elements in the [hugo-octopress theme](https://github.com/parsiya/Hugo-Octopress) are quite minimal:

```
table,
th,
td
 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 3px;
}
th {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
```

which results in a simple table with black cell boders.

To fix this, create a custom `.css` file for the table stylings inside the folder `static/css`, say `static/css/tables.css`. Then change the line for CSS overides in your `config.toml` to point to `customCSS = ["css/tables.css"]`. For reference, you can also take a look at the [hugo-octopress documentation on custom CSS](https://github.com/parsiya/Hugo-Octopress#cssoverride), which you may find helpful.

You can also copy the `hugo-octopress.css` file from the theme into `static/css` and modify the table elements there. Note that unless you override the CSS attributes defined by hugo-octopress, those will also be applied to the tables. Custom CSS styles are added to the header *after* the base theme styles, so any files added to `customCSS` are applied last.